# What is Northwind.EmployeesRow

Tags: asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I am doing a tutorial where you use a templatefield in the gridview control to call a function.

I don't understand the code for the function.  What is the object Northwind.EmployeesRow?

This is the tutorial I am doing.

[Tutorial 12: Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx#aspnett12ustmpfldsvb_topic5)

And this is the code for the function.

```
Protected Function DisplayDaysOnJob(ByVal employee As Northwind.EmployeesRow) As String

    If employee.IsHireDateNull() Then
        Return "Unknown"
    Else
        ' Returns the number of days between the current
        ' date/time and HireDate
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(employee.HireDate)
        Return ts.Days.ToString("#,##0")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I've put in an answer that explains what a "Northwind.EmployeesRow" is, other than that, which part of the function is it that you don't understand? =)

Answer (score 1):

About 3/4 of the way down the tutorial there's the text:

> Container.DataItem returns a
>   DataRowView object that corresponds to
>   the DataSource record bound to the
>   GridViewRow. Its Row property returns
>   the strongly typed
>   Northwind.EmployeesRow

Which indicates to me that Northwind.EmployeesRow is a strongly typed DataRow. You might want to take a read through "[Data Points: Efficient Coding With Strongly Typed DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163877.aspx)" to get a feel for what strongly typed DataSets are and how they work.

In a nuthshell, when using a "normal" dataset, you'd write code like:

```
foreach(DataRow record in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  var employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(record["employeeId"]);
  GivePayriseTo(employeeId);
}
```

With a strongly typed DataRow/DataSet you can do:

```
foreach(Northwind.EmployeesRow employee in Employees.Rows)
{
  GivePayriseTo(employee.EmployeeId);
}
```

Comment: There's also a pretty good explanation from 4guysfromrolla.com: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020806-1.aspx